# How to change Python interpreter path in Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have created an environment **for a specific Python version** using

```
conda create --name my_env python=3.6
```

when I list all the environments using `conda env list` I get a correct list of environments:

```
# conda environments:
#
base        /opt/anaconda
my_env      /opt/anaconda/envs/my_env
```

Inside `/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env/bin/` there is `python` interpreter, which, as expected, has version `3.6`. When I activate the environment

```
source activate my_env
```

it *successfully* activates (i.e. the terminal prompt indicates `(my_env)`).

**However**, when I try to check the python interpreter to which I am currently pointing, `which python` gives me:

```
/opt/anaconda/bin/python
```

which belongs to `base` environment, instead of

```
/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env/bin/python
```

which I would expect.

**Question:** Why did that happen? More importantly, how to change the Python interpreter path to which the environment points? I.e. in this case I'd like `which python` to point to `/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env/bin/python` after activating `my_env`.

Comment: Which version of conda are you using?

Comment: With me it works as expected. My conda version is 4.7.12

Comment: "conda activate and conda deactivate only work on conda 4.6 and later versions" - https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your quick response. It was actually my mistake and you correctly spotted that reproducing the steps mentioned in the question should result in an expected interpreter used (i.e. `Python 3.6`). This is because I was activating the environment using `source activate my_env` not `conda activate my_env` (unlike stated in the question) which resulted in wrong interpreter used. I updated the question accordingly.

PS after few more trials `source activate my_env` results again in expected, proper Python interpreter, not quite sure why is that.

Comment: Also the general question about being able to change the path of the Python interpreter inside the environment still holds I believe. I have not managed to find relevant documentation or similar question on SO.

Comment: I don't think you want to change the path of the Python interpreter in an environment. `conda activate` handles all of that for you. What situations would you want to change the path to the Python executable?

Comment: @darthbith Unfortunately I can no longer reproduce the error. The issue was that, after environment activation,`which python` was returning the path to the `base` environment (even though the terminal prompt showed the name of the proper environment). Will try to have a closer look and try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
conda uninstall /opt/anaconda/bin/python
```