# How to set path to Python executable in JupyterLab somewhere outside Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spss

I need to be able to run JupyterLab on the Python executable in SPSS in order to import some SPSS libraries (spss, spssaux, SpssClient, etc.) in a notebook in JuptyerLab. Based on [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990164/sys-path-insert-inserts-path-to-module-but-imports-are-not-working) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59599679/how-to-change-python-interpreter-path-in-anaconda-environment) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254852/how-to-change-the-jupyter-start-up-folder) Ancadonda/executable-related questions, I've attempted two possible solutions:

1. Paste the relevant libraries from the Python directory in SPSS to the Python directory in Anaconda. I tried this both to the base environment and to the virtual environment I work out of, and tried launching JupyterLab both from the base and from the virtual environment. I copied the files from `C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\27\Python3\Lib\site-packages` to `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib`.
2. Redirect Anaconda to the Python executable in SPSS. I tried to to do that with `sys.path.insert`:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\27\Python3')
```

Attempt #1 results in the following error when I try to import `spss`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11344/2864419669.py in <module>
----> 1 import spss

C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\27\Python3\Lib\site-packages\spss\__init__.py in <module>
    254 __SetErrorMessage()
    255 
--> 256 from .spss import *
    257 from .cursors import *
    258 from .pivotTable import *

C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\27\Python3\Lib\site-packages\spss\spss.py in <module>
     21 
     22 import atexit,os,locale,sys,codecs
---> 23 from . import PyInvokeSpss
     24 from .errMsg import *
     25 

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing PyInvokeSpss: The specified module could not be found.
```

This in spite of having copied `PyInvokeSpss` to `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib`.

#2 doesn't seem to change the path to the executable:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

3. I also have an idea for a third solution, which would be to package the Python that's in SPSS as an iPython [kernel](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html), and then activate that in JupyterLab after it's launched, but I can't figure out a way of doing that.

What's the best direction here for a solution? What am I doing wrong?