# Is there a way to add a Jupyter kernel based on Python executible outside Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

I have a Python executable locally on my machine that has functionality/libraries not available for download in standard Python. I want to be able to import these libraries into JupyterLab, which I believe means changing the iPython kernel that JupyterLab is running on. It's not possible to launch Jupyter from the `C:\ProgramData\` location where it is located.

My compiler/interpreter is currently in Anaconda:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

I want to add an iPython kernel using Python from a different source/path, currently:

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\27\Python3
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645807/change-interpreter-in-jupyter-notebook) answer suggests adding a new kernel like this:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name <kernel_name> --display-name "<Name_to_display>"
```

but neither this answer (nor anywhere in the [iPython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)) does there seem to be an option to pull in Python from somewhere outside Anaconda in creating the new kernel. Is there a way to do this with a kernel, or a different way altogether?

My current workaround is to use `%%script` like this, but that limits the functionality to one cell and means the cell isn't really operating as a typical cell in a notebook anyway:

```
%%script C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\27\Python3
```

Note: This is a specific approach to a more wide-ranging question regarding SPSS external mode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71559028/how-to-set-path-to-python-executable-in-jupyterlab-somewhere-outside-anaconda).

Answer (score 1):

The `python -m ipykernel install --user` implies registration at the *user level*. That is, it any Jupyter instance run by the user would check this registry and include it. Just make sure the `python` in this case in the external one you wish to use as a kernel.

Comment: How do you make sure the `python` is the external one you want to use as a kernel?

Comment: @semblable check `where python`. In your case, might need to navigate (in command line) to `C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\27\Python3` and then run the command.

Comment: Running `python -m ipykernel install --user --name spss "spss"` from that directory, I get the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\27\Python3\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)." Note that I had to open Command Prompt in Administrator mode because the directory is in `C:\ProgramData`.